# How to get correct source map file for a single chunk with CommonsChunkPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin and SourceMapDevToolPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I'm trying to get webpack to output correct sourcemaps for a React project that's split into app and vendor chunks using CommonsChunkPlugin and minified using UglifyJsPlugin. This is for production environment, so I:

- don't want a huge sourcemap for vendor bundle generated.
- don't want the webpack:// sources in map file
- don't want map files for css
- need actual map file output and linked to from the js file so that error monitoring tools can load it

All this seems to be a bit too much for the devtool config option so I'm trying to use SourceMapDevToolPlugin directly with devtool: false.

The relevant parts of webpack config look like this:

```
entry: production ? {
    app: './src/index.jsx',
    vendor: Object.keys(packageDotJson.dependencies)
} : './src/index.jsx',

output: {
    path: production ? './dist' : './assets',
    publicPath: production ? '' : '/',
    filename: production ? 'app.[hash].js' : 'app.js'
},

plugins: production ? [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.[hash].js"),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("app.[hash].css"),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
        filename: "app.[hash].js.map",
        append: "//# sourceMappingURL=[url]",
        moduleFilenameTemplate: "[absolute-resource-path]",
        fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: "[absolute-resource-path]",
        columns: false
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({...})
] : [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({...})
]
```

Sadly, what I'm getting with this is a map file named correctly after my app js file, but containing:

```
{"version":3,"file":"vendor.bundle.05d4e19a02044f47a73a.js","sources":["vendor.bundle.05d4e19a02044f47a73a.js","*"]...}
```

Changing test `to test: /^app\.(.*)\.js$/,` creates a similar map file that maps app.05d4e19a02044f47a73a.js to itself. I can't seem to get the original js and jsx source files in sources.

I've tried playing with the plugin order but that didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

I also find it unclear whether test/include/exclude should point to original sources or the minified js files. With other loaders and plugins it's kinda obvious but not with SourceMapDevToolPlugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, figured out a solution on my own. My SourceMapDevToolPlugin options actually weren't filtering out the vendor bundle, but the filename was set to "app.[hash].js.map", which cause the vendor chunk map to be generated and to overwrite the app chunk map with the same filename.

The correct options are:

```
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx$/],
        exclude: 'vendor',
        filename: "app.[hash].js.map",
        append: "//# sourceMappingURL=[url]",
        moduleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
        fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
    })
```

The minified app.[hash].js is included in the sources but this doesn't seem to cause any problems for the browsers.

`columns: false` is what caused the plugin to only map the minified file to itself for some reason.